# Dropdown menu won't work on phone users

Tags: html, css

My dropdown menu only works on computers, not for phone users. Why does this happen?

I tried to make a `mobileHide` class and hide the dropdown, then add the dropdown content in manually so it's not inside a dropdown anymore, but that looked weird.

```css
li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    color: #1789e8:
}
```

```html
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav-top">
    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>
    <span class="meny-text">More <span class="caret"></span></span>
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="https://rocketprices.net/certified-ps4">Certified - PS4</a>
    <a href="#" style="cursor:not-allowed;" >Certified - PC</a>
    <a href="/faq">FAQ</a>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-staff">Staff</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pop-down is showing only with a hover action, however, for HTML/CSS on mobile devices, hover is not really supported.

You need to design your layout & navigation with this in mind.

As a baseline for all platforms, you should probably go with 'click-and-then-show-dropdown' type of functionality. Then if you truly wanted to add hover functionality for certain platforms (e.g. computers) then make a detection and run some additional code for them. Keep in mind some computer users may have touchscreen monitors! Maybe not everyone will have a cursor to hover with all the time. This is why you really don't see hover menus being used everywhere. Try to find any major website or software that does this.